Medusa.JS - req.body empty in POST middleware
Pulling my hair out over this. Thanks in advance to anyone who can take a look. Any idea why req.body would be empty? Medusa.JS should be using bodyParser by default, yes? It was working earlier today and now it isn't. Clearly something has changed and I can't figure out what. This is my middlewares.ts file:
async function myTestFunc(req: MedusaRequest, res: MedusaResponse, next: MedusaNextFunction) {
  const logger = req.scope.resolve<Logger>('logger');
  console.log("Request BODY!", JSON.stringify(req.body))
  console.log("Request PARAMS!", JSON.stringify(req.params))
  console.log("Customer ID!", JSON.stringify(req.user?.customer_id))
  next();
}

export const config: MiddlewaresConfig = {
  routes: [
    {
      matcher: '/store/carts/:id/line-items',
      middlewares: [authenticateCustomer(), myTestFunc]
    }
  ],
};

Thanks again, much appreciated.

The Medusa documentation clearly says a bodyParser runs by default however, for some reason found that this is only true for certain endpoints.
In most cases for medusa store endpoints, I found I needed to add bodyParser.json() to the middlewares array. As such:
export const config: MiddlewaresConfig = {
  routes: [
    {
      matcher: '/store/carts/:id/line-items',
      middlewares: [authenticateCustomer(), bodyParser.json(), myTestFunc]
    }
  ],
};

I have theories of why this is but they're only theories at this time. If someone can better explain the inner workings of this I would be very much appreciative!!
